# positioning eye icon in input field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want set the eye icon in input field but it is not working correctly when i resize the page.following is may html and css code.

```css
i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"  />

<div class="form-group ml-5 mr-5 icon-div">
  <input class="form-control bg-light" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password*"/>
  <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet as a [mcve] - I fixed your invalid HTML too

Answer (score 3):

Link: https://jsbin.com/nafutiyusa/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"  />

<div class="form-group ml-5 mr-5 icon-div">
  <input class="input form-control bg-light" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password*"/>
  <i class="far fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use row and col class to dispatch the input and icon side by side.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"  />

<div class="form-group ml-5 mr-5 icon-div row  ">
  <input class="form-control bg-light pe-4 col-11" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password*"/>
  <i class="far fa-eye col-1 my-auto " id="togglePassword"></i>
</div>
```